# Glide load image show black when enable proguard

Tags: android, android-glide

I load image from drawable, it usually show black image if I enable proguard
If I build debug (disable proguard) everything look good.

Here is my config in proguard:

```
-keep public class * implements com.bumptech.glide.module.GlideModule
-keep public class * extends com.bumptech.glide.module.AppGlideModule
-keep public enum com.bumptech.glide.load.ImageHeaderParser$** {
**[] $VALUES;
public *;
}
```

Here is my code (glide 4.6.1):

Load image:

```
 Apploader.load("",holder.imageView,MyUtils.getDrawableRessourceID(item.getFlag().toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH).substring(0, 2)));

public static void load(Object uri, ImageView img, int drawable) {
    RequestOptions options = RequestOptions.centerInsideTransform().placeholder(new ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.gray))).error(drawable).diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESOURCE);
    Glide.with(context).load(uri)
            .apply(options)
            .thumbnail(0.5f)
            .into(img);
}
```

Comment: i just use -dontwarn glide.** @phongvan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the reason of this issue:

I used sinkResource in build release so that android studio can't detect some picture I use by name in my project.

I need remove sinkresource or keep drawable folder in proguard

Answer (score 4):

So I've been trying to solve the issue without using `shrinkResources false` because I want to use it but keep specific files.

In my case I was using `.json` to get image names and was using local images to show. But `resource shrinker` thought that those images are unused and deleted all unused images even if I use them by calling `resources.getIdentifier()`. [Doc](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code#strict-reference-checks) says that

> When you use `resources.getIdentifier()`, the resource shrinker behaves defensively by default and marks all resources with a matching name format as potentially used and unavailable for removal.

But I was using `.json` to get image names as an object, so there wasn't any `String` like `"img_%1d"`. That's why `resource shrinker` thought that my images are unused.

**To solve the issue**, you can create `keep.xml` and define resources that you want to keep like below;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:keep="@layout/l_used*_c,@layout/l_used_a,@layout/l_used_b*"
tools:discard="@layout/unused2" />
```

Use comma to add more file and use asterisk character as a wild card.

[Detailed info](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code#shrink-resources)

Comment: although files are with `keep.xml` it becomes black also

Answer (score 3):

it is not because of your proguard file, but when you mention 
`shrinkResources true` in release build type, than while generating application in release mode it will shrink the unused resources (or says resources that aren't mention in java code).

so, keep `shrinkResources false` in release type as:

```
release {
        shrinkResources false
        minifyEnabled true
        zipAlignEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        debuggable false
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

don't forget to include glide dependency in proguard rules

add this below line of code in your proguard-rules.pro file

```
-keep public class * implements com.bumptech.glide.module.GlideModule
-keep public class * extends com.bumptech.glide.module.AppGlideModule
-keep public enum com.bumptech.glide.load.ImageHeaderParser$** {
 **[] $VALUES;
 public *;
 }
 # Uncomment for DexGuard only
 #-keepresourcexmlelements manifest/application/meta-data@value=GlideModule
```

It works without any doubt or You Try this

```
-keep public class * implements com.bumptech.glide.module.GlideModule
-keep public enum com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.ImageHeaderParser$** {
**[] $VALUES;
public *;
}
```

And in code

```
  GlideApp
.with(context)
.load(url)
.centerCrop()
.placeholder(R.drawable.loading_spinner)
.into(myImageView);
```

Comment: hi, please check my question, i added these lines

Comment: Note: I get image from http url is ok but get from drawable, it show black.

Comment: You have to post your code here, then we can understand if there is any issue

Answer (score 0):

why you don't use GlideApp like this

```
public static void load(Object uri, ImageView img, int drawable) {

GlideApp.with(context)
        .load(uri)
        .placeholder(drawable)
        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESOURCE)
        .into(img);
 }
```

and just need add new class for AppGlideModule like this :

```
import com.bumptech.glide.annotation.GlideModule
import com.bumptech.glide.module.AppGlideModule

@GlideModule
class AppGlideModule : AppGlideModule()
```

don't forget to rebuild project after create your AppGlideModule